# Null is not an object (evaluating 'user.foto')

Tags: react-native, axios, react-context

I'm trying to fetch an API with some user data using Axios in React Native, from a context that receive this information from the API and pass to another component that is receiving the context and using it.

**Axios API**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/lucasstartab/euro-api/1.0.0'
})
```

**Context API**

```
export function AuthProvider(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    async function signIn() {
        try {
            const response = await api.get('/user');
            setUser(response.data[0].userInfo);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{signIn, user}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Component that uses the context**

```
export function UserInfo({ navigation }) {
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Host>
                <View style={styles.padding}>
                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <UserPhoto imageUri={user.foto} size='BIG' border={4}/>
                        <View style={styles.ProfileAndDesc}>
                            <Text style={styles.profile}>{user.name}</Text>                
                            <Text style={styles.desc}>Filial {user.filial}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

**I don't know why this error is appearing, I checked the API URL but it's working normally. The error:**

[image: Error]

No more ways on my journey trying to solve this, hope to get an answer, thx!

Comment: from the looks of it, maybe there is no object key named "foto".
it'll be better, if you provide a link to a GitHub repo/gist with a minimal working code for better analyzing it.

Comment: here is what I get from the API url: 
`[
  {
    "token": "a1b2c3",
    "userInfo": {
      "name": "Lucas",
      "email": "lucas@startab.com.br",
      "password": "Senha.123",
      "filial": "Sudeste",
      "foto": "https://github.com/lucastso.png",
      "fotoCapa": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639208067515-99bccfacb05c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
    }
  }
]`

Answer (score 0):

After some days trying to solve, reading the code again and again, I realized that **I started the "user" state NULL on the context**, so I **changed to an object "{}"** and it was solved.